# How do I auto-accept all website cookie warnings?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, cookies

Every time I go to any website in the UK it asks me if I accept cookies or not.

Is there a way to disable this question and accept all cookies universally?

Comment: Judging by the different answers, you should clarify the question. Is "it" the browser or the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do is create an empirical script for auto press the button...

Every *european* web site must show the banner but there's no a standard.
**The banner is shown even if you have the more flexible cookie policy set on your browser.** there's no thing you can do (without external programs of course)

Read here, the new [EU legislation on cookies](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you edit [hostname pattern](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?hl=en) in

*chrome settings - advanced settings - content settings - cookies - manage exceptions*

and allow `[*.]uk`

[image]

Comment: The fact that a browser technically accepts cookies, won't make a website stop asking for permission?

Comment: I don't understand if that's a question or a comment. I also have no idea if chrome still does this.